# Does a linear transformation of sets preserve subset properties?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose there are two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ (not necessarily convex). Let $A$ be an arbitrary matrix, and say $AS_1$ is the set of vectors $y$ satisfying: 
$
y \in AS_1 \text{ if } y = Ax \text{ for some } x \in S_1. 
$

A similar definition holds for $S_2$.

If $AS_1 \subset AS_2$ , does it mean $S_1 \subset S_2$ for any matrix $A$ and any sets $S_1$ and $S_2$? or are there special cases?

Comment: Do you mean your sets to be subsets of $\mathbb R^n$? This question doesn't make sense for arbitrary sets.

Comment: yes, subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is not specific to matrix multiplication.  If we have any function $f$ (from any set to any set) and subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of the domain, if $S_1 \subset S_2$ then $f[S_1] \subset f[S_2]$.  That is, pointwise application preserves the subset relation *going forward*. (Here $f[S]$ denotes the set $\{f(x) : x \in S\}$, which is the pointwise image of the set $S$ under the function $f$.)

What you are asking is the converse.  The answer is negative: if $f[S_1] \subset f[S_2]$ then it does not follow that $S_1 \subset S_2$.  It follows if $f$ is injective (one-to-one,) but if $f$ is not injective then you can always find a counterexample.  To see this, let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be distinct points with $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  Let $S_1 = \{x_1\}$ and $S_2 = \{x_2\}$.  Then the pointwise images are equal: $f[S_1] = \{f(x_1)\} = \{f(x_2)\} = f[S_2]$ but the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are distinct (and in fact neither one is a subset of the other.)

In your situation the function $f$ is multiplication by a matrix $A$; that is, $f(x) = A\textbf{x}$.  The same argument still applies.  Note that multiplication by $A$ represents an injective function if and only if the nullspace of $A$ is the trivial subspace $\{\textbf{0}\}$.  If the nullspace of $A$ is nontrivial, then one counterexample to your question (besides the general form of counterexample given above) is given by letting $S_1$ be the nullspace of $A$ and letting $S_2 = \{\textbf{0}\}$.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. This answer makes total sense to me. In the specific problem I am trying to solve, A is a tall matrix (more rows than columns). That means it has a trivial nullspace, and the converse that I asked for holds. Am i right?

Comment: @NSR A matrix with more rows than columns can still have a nontrivial nullspace.  But if the nullspace really is trivial, then you are correct that the converse holds.

Comment: Actually, I have another question. What if f() is multivalued? So a single x maps to multiple f(x).

Comment: @NSR Since there is a counterexample with a (ordinary) function, and every function is also a multi-valued function, then there is still a counterexample.  (If by multi-valued function you mean to exclude the case of ordinary functions, then one could modify the counterexample slightly.)  You could ask maybe about "injective" multi-valued functions, but I'm not sure what the definition of injectivity for multi-valued functions would be.  Also I don't see any conenction between multi-valued functions and matrices; are we forgetting about matrices now?

Comment: I see. Thanks. Yes, now I was talking about nonlinear mappings. I wanted to see how far this can be pushed :)